# Mismatched icons?

Tags: support, bug

Since yesterday I've noticed that all of the small icons used in the "Hot Network Questions" pane, as well as some of the community nav menu (the SE icon at top-right) are all mixed up. This seems to be localized to the SF&F and SF&F Meta boards.

I've tried clearing my cache to no avail. Is anyone else having his issue? and how can I/we fix it?

See attached screenshots for examples. Not that in the second image, showing the nav menu, only the SF

[image]

[image]

Comment: Huh, I haven't seen this issue. But I would like to see what [pets.se] think about circular reasoning, or how to cope with nuclear blasts at [workplace.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would appear to be the same issue as what has been highlighted on SO meta recently. This question explains the same issue as yours: [I'm seeing the wrong site icons in my profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374128/4631427) and from there it is caused by the same issue that is explained in this question: [Hot network questions have broken icons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374126/4631427).

See the [answer by @Adam Lear♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374134/4631427) for the reason:

> This happens sometimes when we roll out a new set of icons due to how our build process works. I'll see what I can do about kicking the affected cachebreakers, but either way it'll resolve itself ... eventually. Caching is fun!

[This comment by @Catija♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315468/incorrect-icons-on-hot-network-questions#comment1033927_315468) on main meta explains why the issue occurred recently. The follow up comment tells us the rename was "Health to Medical Sciences".

> We're renaming a site and changing its favicon and a couple of other sites' icons... messing with them always causes this for a few people. We're poking at it and it should be fixed soon.

Comment: FWIW I personally haven't seen this issue.

Comment: I kind of figured it was something along those lines. I'll just have to content myself with being irritated. Thanks for your reply.